# Popup without redirection

Tags: java, spring, popup, try-catch, alert

### Subject closed.

**Hello,**
I have a popup that appears on my web page, in case an error occurs in my block catch. It displays correctly, but when I close it, it redirects me to the url of my method (which can't be functional because an error has been raised). I would simply like that when I close my popup, there is no redirection, but simply that I stay on my current web page. How can I do this in Java and Spring? Thank you.

```
catch (Exception e) {
   response.reset();
   logger.info("ERROR - (" +e+")");
                
   PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  
   response.setContentType("text/html");  
   out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");  
   out.println("alert('myText');");  
   out.println("</script>");
}
```

Comment: Try to add event listener of error in your script, such as window.addEventListener("error", () => {}), to help process error of page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Being a beginner, at what level should I add your proposal? Thank you!

Comment: I found an alternative, by modifying my existing code. Thanks anyway for the feedback!